# GroceryCRUD display_as not working

Tags: grocery-crud

I have a issue with the display_as.

I follow the example

```
$crud->display_as('lastName','Last Name');
$crud->display_as('firstName','First Name');
$crud->display_as('jobTitle','Job Title');
```

But the name does not change.

does this have something to do with the 
application\libraries\Grocery_CRUD.php

where

```
protected $display_as = array();
```

Since it is protected and i have written my code in a public function?

I have been reading a lot but cant find anything about this.

grateful for any help

Thanks

```
public function employees_example()
{
$crud = new grocery_CRUD();

$crud->set_table('employees');
$crud->columns('lastName','firstName','email','jobTitle');
$crud->fields('lastName','firstName','extension','email','jobTitle');

$crud->display_as('lastName','Last Name');
$crud->display_as('firstName','First Name');
 $crud->display_as('jobTitle','Job Title');

$output = $crud->render();

$this->_example_output($output);
}

but it does not change the display_as names
```

Answer (score 0):

Well my friend, that protected variable declaration you saw in the code is the part of the code - the variable is protected, not the function. If you find in the code - the function is not protected.

It is hard to believe that the function ain't working unless you have done some personal alterations to the same. That is the base functionality that have existed for years and is working perfectly fine.

Only scenario where it might not work is .. in case you have specified your own set of fields / columns and that dose not include those fields and in that case it will not work.

For a proper answer - i will recommend you put up the code some place - the whole of the code for the method - and along with the table structure. That will help one identify as where and what is the issue and how can we reach to a proper solution.